# Chrome Scrollable Div Bug

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, scrollbar

Interesting bug in Chrome. If a scrollable div is off screen when the page initially loads, then that scrollable div is not scrollable by way of mouse wheel or touch pad gestures until it is given focus (by double clicking somewhere within its element, or selecting text inside of it).

**Update**
This bug is documented here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417345  It remains unfixed as of May 2015. The thread provides some interesting possible solutions with javascript, but I would like to see if anyone has any alternate suggestions for a fix, possibly not involving JS

**The Bug**
When you click on the button to "Show Side Container", the side container will slide into view, and the main container will slide out of view. If you immediately try to scroll **using the mouse wheel or two finger gesture on a laptop track pad**, nothing will happen.  You can use page up and page down on the keyboard however, these do work.  You can of course also use the actual scroll by by clicking on it with a mouse.

In firefox and IE, you can use the mouse wheel to scroll on this element

**Example**
http://codepen.io/msorrentino/full/aOYaOM/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="page-container">
        <button class="show-side">Show Side Container</button>

    </div>
    <div class="side-container">
        <button class="close-side">Close Side Container</button>
        <div class="large-content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 html,
        body,
        *,
        *:after,
        *:before {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .wrapper {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
        }


        .page-container, .side-container {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            border: 5px solid;
            overflow-y: auto;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0, 1);
            transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0, 1), transform 0.2s cubic-bezier(0.68, 0, 0, 1);
        }

        .page-container {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
            transform: translate(0,0);
        }

        .page-container-hidden {
            -webkit-transform: translate(-100%,0);
            transform: translate(-100%,0);
        }

        .side-container {
            -webkit-transform: translate(100%,0);
            transform: translate(100%,0);
        }
        .side-container-visible {
            -webkit-transform: translate(0,0);
            transform: translate(0,0);
        }

        .large-content {
            height: 2000px;
        }
```

**JS**

```
$('.show-side').click(function(){
            $('.page-container').addClass('page-container-hidden');
            $('.side-container').addClass('side-container-visible');
        });
        $('.close-side').click(function(){
            $('.page-container').removeClass('page-container-hidden');
            $('.side-container').removeClass('side-container-visible');
        });
```

**It gets more interesting**
If you make the original "page-container" element have enough content that to force it to have overflow, then the "side-container" element no longer displays the aforementioned bug! 
http://codepen.io/msorrentino/full/WvzgQZ/

Any thoughts on what is happening here are welcome, and any possible fixes would be very welcome.

Comment: Of course! The element has no overflow, so there is nothing to scroll. there is no bug, it is how it should be.

Comment: both page-container and side-container have overflow-y: auto. and side-container has a placeholder div "large-content" which has a very large height property set which causes overflow.  Not sure what you are talking about @yak613.

Answer (score 2):

Came across this question when I encountered a very similar problem with an off-screen menu that moves on-screen when toggled.

Here's the relevant HTML and CSS, simplified:

```
<div class="menu">
  <!-- long list of menu items here -->
</div>

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: transform ease 125ms;
}
.menu--active {
  transform: translateX(0);
}
```

`.menu--active` is toggled with a button.

Though you're looking for a non-JS solution, I thought I'd post the cleanest workaround I've found in case people end up here with the same problem.

The workaround is to simply force a focus state on the `div` *after* the transition has completed. To do this, you first have to give the `div` a `tabindex` so that it can be focused.

```
<div class="menu" tabindex="-1">
  <!-- long list of menu items here -->
</div>
```

(A value of `-1` should keep the `div` out of the normal tab order.)

Then, using a bit of delayed jQuery, focus on the `div`. This should be invoked along with whatever logic you use to "activate" your `div`.

```
setTimeout( function() {
  $('.menu').focus();
},150);
```

The time here is `150` milliseconds, which is just after the transition should have completed. A value equal to that of the transition duration would probably work too, but I set it longer just to be safe.

A more complete example might be:

```
$('.menuButton').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').addClass('menu--active');
  setTimeout( function() {
    $('.menu').focus();
  },150);
});
```

Finally, you probably won't want the focus `outline` on the focused `div`, so you might choose to remove it with an `outline: none` in the style rule for your `div`. In my project, but not in the original example in the question, this actually broke focus on the `div`, and it went back to being un-scrollable. So I did this instead:

```
.menu:focus {
  outline-color: transparent;
}
```

I forked the original example and included this solution here: http://codepen.io/johntobinme/full/MaPMgY

Comment: Thank you for the `tabindex` suggestion. It saved my day ;)

Answer (score -2):

You have `overflow-y` set to `auto`, meaning it will create a scroll bar for off screen content. Since `.large-content` has such a large height, it goes off screen. Simply set `overflow-y` to none and this will no longer occur. Not a bug, just user error.

Comment: This is not addressing my question. I will edit my OP to make it more clear. I am not complaining about a scroll bar. I am complaining that in Chrome when you get to that screen you cannot use your mouse wheel to scroll until you do something to gain focus on that div (such as double-clicking anywhere, or selecting text).  This is a Chrome specific bug other browsers do not have that problem.